# How to get Places AutocompletePredictions Result in newly released "Places sdk " by google?

Tags: android, api, dictionary, gradle, google-places

When debug apps at deprecated dependency it shows

> AutocompletePredictionBuffer{status=Status{statusCode=CANCELED, resolution=null}}

I have tried several solutions about API key. My API key is working fine. I have used the following dependency. Old one is not working right now. But when i used newly released libraries for places `GEO_DATA_API` not found.

So how can I get the AutocompletePredictions Result using updated libraries?

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1' // Old version
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0' // Updated version
}
```

[image: After debugging this returns in android studio]

Comment: Seems like the basic structure is updated in new SDK. Please check this carefully: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: Thanks vai... But not solve yet

Comment: Done.. Problem Solved

Comment: Would you please share the update what you have done to solve this?